# adding a tuple component as pos-tags to list list of tuples by nltk

Tags: python, list, tags, tuples, nltk

I am working  on a name entity recognition(NER) for recognition of some lables for  a text.

I want to use `nltk` and the problem is that I have the data in this format (list of list of tuples) which basically looks like this (4 samples):

```
df[0:5]:
[[('Appendix', 'None'), ('B', 'None')],
 [('On', 'None'),
  ('the', 'None'),
  ('Table', 'None'),
  ('of', 'None'),
  ('Oppositions', 'None'),
  ('in', 'None'),
  ('Chapter', 'None'),
  ('15', 'NUM')],
 [('by', 'None'),
  ('Yaakov', 'None'),
  ('Zik', 'None'),
  ('Table', 'None'),
  ('i', 'None')],
 [('Initial', 'None'),
  ('positions', 'None'),
  ('of', 'None'),
  ('Mars', 'None'),
  ('in', 'None'),
  ('Chapter 15 ', 'None'),
  ('computed', 'None'),
  ('with', 'None'),
  ('Guide 9 ', 'None'),
  ('using', 'None'),
  ('JPL', 'GEOM'),
  ('DE430', 'GEOM')],
 [('General', 'None'), ('notes', 'None')]]
```

I want to add to each tuple pos_tag without changing the construction of the data.

The desired result should be like this

```
[[('Appendix','CS', 'None'), ('B',  'NC', 'None')],
 [('On',  'NC',  'None'),
  ('the',  'NC',  'None'),
  ('Table',  'NC',  'None'),
  ('of', 'Fp' 'None'),
  ('Oppositions','Fp',  'None'),
  ('in', 'Fp' 'None'),
  ('Chapter', 'Fp', 'None'),
  ('15', 'Fp', 'NUM')],
 [('by', 'None'),
  ('Yaakov', 'Fp', 'None'),
  ('Zik', 'None'),
  ('Table', 'Fp', 'None'),
  ('i', 'Fp', 'None')],
 [('Initial', 'Fp', 'None'),
  ('positions', 'Fp', 'None'),
  ('of', 'Fp', 'None'),
  ('Mars', 'Fp', 'None'),
  ('in', 'Fp', 'None'),
  ('Chapter 15 ', 'Z', 'None'),
  ('computed', 'Fp', 'None'),
  ('with', 'Fp', 'None'),
  ('Guide 9 ', 'Fp', 'None'),
  ('using', 'None'),
  ('JPL', 'Fp', 'GEOM'),
  ('DE430', 'Fp', 'GEOM')],
 [('General', 'Z', 'None'), ('notes', ''Fp' 'None')]]
```

As is given, I want to add the pos-tag  in each tuple by nltk.pos_tag(sent)

Generally speaking, how can I add a component to list of list of tuples in way that the result is again same list of list of tuples?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a little vague but here is a quick solution based on my understanding. Assuming that you want to keep the order intact and want to insert an item into a position of the tuple:

```
to_add = '*' # Replace this value with the actual data you want to insert such as pos_tag
position_to_add = 1 # Replace this value with the actual position to insert into

result = []
for lst in df:
    ret_li = []
    for tpl in lst:
        # new_tpl = [*tpl]
        # new_tpl.append('None')
        new_tpl = tuple([*tpl[0:position_to_add]] + [to_add] + [*tpl[position_to_add:]])
        ret_li.append(new_tpl)

    result.append(ret_li)
```

Comment: that works perfectly for a  adding constant value ! many thanks. now I am working to add  this item to each tuple. I have it.  I updated the result, only last question, tagging a word not a sentence by nltk does not effect the quality of tagging ?